# Trouble passing parameters between scenes

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having a problem with this code I am writing. The project is a password keeper app, and for this current sprint I created a `Password` model and another class to hold an `ArrayList` of `Password`s called `PasswordList`. I've created a `PasswordList` object in every controller class as a `private` variable and pass it along by loading the controller of the next scene and setting the `PasswordList` with the current controller's `PasswordList` (so that the same list is passed throughout the whole project). However, when creating a new `Password` object, adding it to this `PasswordList`, then switching scenes, the `PasswordList` is `null`.

So, I have a `PasswordUI` which is the viewer, and from there a user can click on the "Add" button to view the `CreatePasswordUI`. I've tested to make sure that the password is created and added successfully to the `PasswordList` by printing it to the console and using the debugger, and everything checks out. I can even go back to add another password, and the list still has all the previous `Password` objects created. Yet, in the `PasswordUI`, the `PasswordList` is still coming up as `null` even though I am passing the `PasswordList` from the previous scene.

I am stuck and do not know what to do.

```
public class PasswordUIController implements Initializable {

    private PasswordList passList;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    TreeTableView passwordInfo;
    @FXML
    TreeTableColumn<String,String> acctColumn;
    @FXML
    Parent root;
    @FXML
    private void backButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainMenuUI.fxml"));     
        Pane mainMenuUI = (Pane)loader.load();          
        MainMenuController controller = loader.<MainMenuController>getController();
        controller.setPassList(passList);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainMenuUI); 
        stage.setTitle("Main Menu");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    @FXML
    private void addButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CreatePasswordUI.fxml"));     
        Pane createPassUI = (Pane)loader.load();          
        CreatePasswordUIController controller = loader.<CreatePasswordUIController>getController();
        controller.setPassList(passList);

        Scene scene = new Scene(createPassUI); 
        stage.setTitle("Create Password");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        PasswordList pList = passList;
        if (pList != null) {
            ArrayList<Password> thePasswords = pList.getPasswordList();           
            TreeItem<String> passwords = new TreeItem<>("Passwords");
            for (int i = 0; i < thePasswords.size(); i++) {
                Password thePass = thePasswords.get(i);
                //Creating tree items
                TreeItem<String> username = new TreeItem<>("Username: " + thePass.getUsername());
                TreeItem<String> password = new TreeItem<>("Password: " + thePass.getPassword());
                TreeItem<String> comment = new TreeItem<>("Comment: " + thePass.getComment());

                //Creating the root element
                TreeItem<String> account = new TreeItem<>(thePass.getAccount());
                account.setExpanded(true);

                //Adding tree items to the root
                account.getChildren().setAll(username, password, comment);   
                passwords.getChildren().add(account);
            }
            //Creating a column
            acctColumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Account");

            //Defining cell content
            acctColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                @Override
                public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String> param){
                    return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue());
                }
            });

            //Creating a tree table view
            passwordInfo = new TreeTableView<>();
            passwordInfo.setRoot(passwords);
            passwordInfo.getColumns().add(acctColumn);
        } else {

        }
    }    

    /**
     * @return the passList
     */
    public PasswordList getPassList() {
        return passList;
    }

    /**
     * @param passList the passList to set
     */
    public void setPassList(PasswordList passList) {
        this.passList = passList;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class CreatePasswordUIController implements Initializable {

    private PasswordList passList;
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @FXML
    Parent root;
    @FXML
    TextField accountTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField usernameTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passwordTxt;
    @FXML
    TextField passwordTxt2;
    @FXML
    TextArea commentArea;
    @FXML
    TextField passwordGeneratorTxt;
    @FXML
    Label rating;
    @FXML
    Label matching;
    @FXML
    Label incorrect;
    @FXML
    private void backButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainMenuUI.fxml"));     
        Pane mainMenuUI = (Pane)loader.load();          
        MainMenuController controller = loader.<MainMenuController>getController();
        controller.setPassList(passList);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainMenuUI); 
        stage.setTitle("Main Menu");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    @FXML
     private void submitButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
        String account = accountTxt.getText();
        String username = usernameTxt.getText();
        String password = passwordTxt.getText();
        String password2 = passwordTxt2.getText();
        String comment = commentArea.getText();
        if (password.equals(password2) && username.length()>2) {
            PasswordList pList = passList;
            Password thePass = new Password(account, username, password, comment);
            pList.addPassword(thePass);
            Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("PasswordUI.fxml"));     
            Pane passwordUI = (Pane)loader.load();          
            PasswordUIController controller = loader.<PasswordUIController>getController();
            controller.setPassList(pList);

            Scene scene = new Scene(passwordUI); 
            stage.setTitle("Password");
            stage.setScene(scene);    
            stage.show();   
        } else {
            incorrect.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    @FXML
    private void generateButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        PasswordGenerator passGen = new PasswordGenerator();
        String password = passGen.generatePassword(true);
        passwordGeneratorTxt.setText(password); 
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        PasswordRater rater = new PasswordRater();
        passwordTxt.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldVal,Object newVal) {
               String password = passwordTxt.getText();
               rater.setPassword(password);
               String ratingStr = rater.displayLevel();
               rating.setText(ratingStr);
               rating.setVisible(true);
               if (passwordTxt.getText().equals(passwordTxt2.getText()) && !password.equals("")) {
                    matching.setText("Good!");
               }
               else
               {
                   matching.setText("Passwords do not match.");
               }
            }
        });
        passwordTxt2.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldVal,Object newVal) {
                String password = passwordTxt.getText();
                String password2 = passwordTxt2.getText();
                if (password.equals(password2) && !password.equals("")) {
                    matching.setText("Good!");
                } else {
                    matching.setText("Passwords do not match.");
                }
                matching.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }    

    /**
     * @return the passList
     */
    public PasswordList getPassList() {
        return passList;
    }

    /**
     * @param passList the passList to set
     */
    public void setPassList(PasswordList passList) {
        this.passList = passList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with having a new password list in every controller is that everytime a new instance is created , you are basically Looking at a singleton approach .
Either you can try singleton like only one object is created throughout the application or for a simpler approach you can have a single static list in your main class and then reuse it in the subsequent contorllers.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the controller in the fxml file using the `fx:controller` attribute and do not specify a controller factory, `FXMLLoader` procedes as follows:

1. `load()` method is entered
2. when the `fx:controller` attribute is read a new instance of the controller class specified in the attribute value is created.
3. Any elements with a `fx:id` attributes are injected to the approprieate fields of the controller instance.
4. The controller's `initialize` method is called, if there is one
5. `load()` completes returning the element created for the root element of the fxml file

For

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("CreatePasswordUI.fxml"));     
Pane createPassUI = (Pane)loader.load();          
CreatePasswordUIController controller = loader.<CreatePasswordUIController>getController();
controller.setPassList(passList);
```

to work however you'd need a different order of operations:

```
1.
2.
3.
5.
controller.setPassList(passList);
4.
```

If you want create the controller this way, move the code for initializing the `TreeTableView` to the `setPassList` method.

BTW: I'm pretty sure creating a new `TreeTableView` is not what you want. Instead you should set the data to the existing `TreeTableView` created by the `FXMLLoader`:

**PasswordUIController**

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // displaying the item itself in the TreeTableColumn defys
    // the purpose of Tree**Table**View, but we'll ignore this here
    acctColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<String> call(TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<String, String> param){
            return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getValue());
        }
    });
}

public void setPassList(PasswordList passList) {
    if (passList == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.passList = passList;

    ArrayList<Password> thePasswords = passList.getPasswordList();           
    TreeItem<String> passwords = new TreeItem<>("Passwords");
    for (int i = 0; i < thePasswords.size(); i++) {
        Password thePass = thePasswords.get(i);
        //Creating tree items
        TreeItem<String> username = new TreeItem<>("Username: " + thePass.getUsername());
        TreeItem<String> password = new TreeItem<>("Password: " + thePass.getPassword());
        TreeItem<String> comment = new TreeItem<>("Comment: " + thePass.getComment());

        //Creating the root element
        TreeItem<String> account = new TreeItem<>(thePass.getAccount());
        account.setExpanded(true);

        //Adding tree items to the root
        account.getChildren().setAll(username, password, comment);   
        passwords.getChildren().add(account);
    }

    // set content of the TreeTableView
    passwordInfo.setRoot(passwords);
}
```

---

There are other ways of passing data to a fxml controller. You can find some good answers here: [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml)